# select/deselect random multiple dates

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

on click I want `select/deselect`  random multiple dates. user should be able to select multiple dates (`Ex: I should be able to select 2 Dec 2014, 8 Dec 2014 and 18 dec 2014. all these three dates should look selected.`). Current I m using [DLSCalendar](https://github.com/PeteC/DSLCalendarView). The [DLSCalendar](https://github.com/PeteC/DSLCalendarView) supports single date selection and range selection.
any others lib that supports the above mention functionality is welcome

Thanks.

Comment: So what do you want to know?  How to generate multiple random dates?

Comment: selecte multiple random dates : Ex: I should be able to select 2 Dec 2014, 8 Dec 2014 and 18 dec 2014. all these three dates should look selected.

Comment: So the DLSCalendar framework only lets you select single dates or a contiguous range, and you need a calendar view that lets you select noncontiguous dates? You should edit your question to say that if that's what you're trying to ask.

Comment: Since DLSCalendar is open source, why not fork it and add a feature for selecting multiple dates and submit that update to github?

Comment: Hey @DuncanC, I have change DLSCalendar as per my requirement, I will add it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes in [DSLCalendarView](https://github.com/Yuyutsu/DSLCalendarView) related to **select/deselect** random multiple dates.

**Ex: I should be able to select 2 Dec 2014, 8 Dec 2014 and 18 dec 2014. all these three dates should look selected.**

Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Please be more precise in what you want to accomplish.

If you are trying to create random dates in objective-c you can do the following:

```
// Objective-c Random date picker

//SET Day integers

int lowerday    = 1;
int upperday    = 31;

//SET Month integers

int lowermonth  = 1;
int uppermonth  = 12;

//SET Year integers

int loweryear   = 1;
int upperyear  = 2025; //Or any random year, but always higher then loweryear!

//Generate random Date

int monthvalue = lowermonth + arc4random() % (uppermonth - lowermonth); //Month
int yearvalue  = loweryear  + arc4random() % (upperyear  - loweryear ); //Year


//Days differ each month so we should account for that
NSArray  *highmonth      =@[@"1",@"3",@"5",@"7",@"8",@"10",@"12"]; //Months with 31 days
NSArray  *lowmonth       =@[@"4",@"6",@"9",@"11"];                 //Months with 30 days
NSString *secondmonth    =@"2";
NSString *random_month   =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",monthvalue];

int dayvalue;

if ([highmonth containsObject:random_month]) {
        //Do nothing the upperday is correctly set
}else if([lowmonth containsObject:random_month]){
        upperday=30;
}else if([random_month isEqualToString:secondmonth]){
        //To options 28 or 29 days
    if (fmod(monthvalue, 1.0) == 0.0) {
        //29 Days
        upperday=29;
    }else{
        //28 Days
        upperday=28;
    }
}

dayvalue   = lowerday  + arc4random() % (upperday  - lowerday ); //Day

//Create NSDate and give our random numbers

NSString        *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d-%d-%d",dayvalue,monthvalue,yearvalue];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSDate          *dateFromString=[dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

//Check Random Date

if (dateFromString==nil) {
    NSLog(@"Could not create random date");
}else{
    NSLog(@"Succes! The Date was: %@",dateFromString);
}
```